# Spring : BeanFactory not initialized or already closed

Tags: java, spring

When i am adding **cacheclients.xml** file in **applicationcontext.xml** i am getting below exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:921)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4980)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5626)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and my file cacheclient.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

            <bean name="announcementClient" class="com.ccc.service.cache.clients.GenericCompanyCacheClient" init-method="init">
                <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
                <property name="cacheName" value="valid_data"/>
                <property name="dBQuery" value="SELECT * from validstatus"  />
                <property name="clientName" value="ValidStatus" />
                <property name="moduleName" value="VALID_Status" />
            </bean>
            <bean name="quarterlyResultsClient" class="com.ccc.service.cache.clients.GenericCompanyCacheClient" init-method="init">
                <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
                <property name="cacheName" value="valid_data"/>
                <property name="dBQuery" value="SELECT * from validuserrole" />
                <property name="clientName" value="ValidUserRole" />
                <property name="moduleName" value="VALID_USER_ROLE" />
            </bean>


</beans>
```

in the applicationcontext.xml file i added this

```
<import resource="CacheClients.xml" />
```

When i am removing above import everything working fine

Web.xml entries

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Comment: Show How is web.xml defined to access apicationcontext.xml file?

Comment: edited question with the web.xml entry

Answer (score 0):

Are you using tomcat in eclipse.
then refresh the project,maven build it and maven update the project
and let me know if you are still facing this issue.

Comment: Yes same Issue brother